# How to calculate a large matrix of zeros and ones in R quickly and efficiently

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have been using R for some time, but am not that good at optimizing my code for performance.

Given a vector `Y`, of length `t`, I am trying to generate a square matrix of order `t` , so that its `i`th row corresponds to $1_{Y_i < Y_j}$ for all `j = 1, 2, ..., t`. So this is a 0 / 1 binary matrix.

```
Y <- matrix(0, length(t), length(t))
for(i in 1:length(t))  Y[i, ] <- (t[i] <= t)
```

However, I don't believe this is the most efficient way of doing it, mainly looking at the size of the object. It's the same size, in bytes, as a dense matrix. My goal is to extend this to large `t`, but I believe the computing speed, and storage space for such a matrix will take too long. Is there a quicker and more efficient way to store and calculate this matrix?

Comment: You haven't defined `t` in your code, so your code doesn't work because `t` is the transpose function.

Comment: a for loop should be quite fast, but you could speed it up by just calculating the upper or lower triangle: so approx half the calculations / storage.

Comment: You're trying to expand your custom sparse-matrix column representation. Strictly we don't care about the individual numeric values of `t`, only their relative rank: `t = rank(t)` gives the exact same output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, we can use:

```
outer(t, t, "<=") + 0L
## operator `"<="` returns TRUE / FALSE logical, 
## add an integer 0 to make a 0 / 1 binary integer matrix
```

Let's have a quick test, comparing with your reference `for` loop.

```
set.seed(0); t <- runif(5)  ## reproducible data

outer(t, t, "<=") + 0L
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    0    0    0    1
#[2,]    1    1    1    1    1
#[3,]    1    0    1    1    1
#[4,]    1    0    0    1    1
#[5,]    0    0    0    0    1

Y <- matrix(0, nrow=length(t), ncol=length(t))
for(i in 1:length(t)) {
  Y[i, ] <- t[i] <= t
}

Y
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    0    0    0    1
#[2,]    1    1    1    1    1
#[3,]    1    0    1    1    1
#[4,]    1    0    0    1    1
#[5,]    0    0    0    0    1
```

We get the same result. Bingo!!

---

**Note:**

People have read the history of edit of this answer. A method with `sparseMatrix` is given. I initially thought using a sparse matrix and column pivoting will improve efficiency, but no. Benchmark shows `outer` is 6 or more times faster. Therefore, though I feel quite sad, I have to trash those large chunk of my answer.

Comment: I *dont think* using sparse matrix will save storage space if it the matrix is not actually sparse  - (may be less effcient??)

Comment: Sorry, im not sure i understand, what do you mean by "If we do both row and column pivoting, we end up with a triangular matrix". (but if half a sparse matrix is non-zero, then i think this may be more inefficient to store than a full matrix)

Comment: Re the sparse matrix: if half are zero then it does not mean that it size of the object is half the size. Try `object.size(f(t, FALSE)) ; object.size(f(t, TRUE))`. Also, a problem i find with outer is it can run into memory problems as the vector increases in length more than a loop will.

Comment: Strictly we don't care about the individual numeric values of `t`, only their relative rank: `t = rank(t)` gives the exact same output. For this example that's `4 1 2 3 5`. Note that the increasing subsequence `1 2 3 5` gives an upper-diagonal ones matrix (well at least the rightmost 4x4); that can probably be exploited. But can you pick a less toy example, say length-12? and post your seeded-random vector?

Comment: Specifically, the consecutive run `1,2,3` can be replaced with an `upper.tri()` ones matrix. I think that can be exploited.